# Minor alignment issue in the Ask Question page

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions

In the bottom of the [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page, there is a checkbox option as

> Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style

In the text content, the link "share your knowledge, Q&A-style" doesn't contains the proper bottom padding.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Alignment issue]